# how to disable hover effect when once focused

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
.form-signin input[type="text"]:focus{
 
 border: 1px solid blue;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"]:focus{
 
 border: 1px solid blue;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow:none;
 
}



.form-signin input[type="text"]:hover{
 
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"]:hover{
 
 border: 1px solid black;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow:none;
 
}

.form-signin input[type="text"]
{
 border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 500px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"]
{
    display: block; 
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 500px;
 border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
</body>

<form class="form-signin">
                <input type="text"  class="form-control" method="post" placeholder="Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email'" required  />
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'password'"  required>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

i have added :hover and :focus on input fields for email and password on my webpage. the problem is when once either field is focused i.e clicked on, the hover effect still remains active, i want to disable that. to be more precise let us assume i am giving border: color property for :hover and :focus as follows

default --> grey

hover --> black

focus --> blue

so according to above assumptions after clicking on either of input fields, BOX should turn blue and no matter if my mouse hovers over the box it should remain blue, but the damn! box turns black >:( i hope i am not messing your brain's up.

to give you better understanding for what i want to acieve i am leaving link down below for topcoder's login page

https://accounts.topcoder.com/connect

here's the snippet showing what issue i have

Comment: object.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is box shadow and thicker border rendering on hover. I put this code in the inspector and it seems it gets rid of your hover problem.

```
input.widest.ng-pristine.ng-empty.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required.ng-touched:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
}
```

Comment: as i am not using the code code from reference website directly, i am unable to do what you just told, i have edited the question and added my CSS and HTML code, please can you refer to that and give me an answer? any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood your problem. Here is what you should try:

    .form-signin input[type="text"]:hover:not(:focus){
     border: 1px solid black;
     box-shadow: none;
    }

    .form-signin input[type="password"]:hover:not(:focus){
     border: 1px solid black;
     outline: none;
     box-shadow:none; 
    }

I just added :not(:focus).